# Finding number of relationships in common in Postgres SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres table of relationships between firms and clients:

```
Clients

ID
1
2
```

```
Firms

ID
A
C
```

```
Relationships

Firm, Client
A, 1
C, 1
C, 2
```

For each firm-client combination, I'd like to get the number of firms that: (1) the client uses, AND (2) at least one of the firm's clients uses.

For instance, above, the result for firm A would be:

```
Firm, Client, # of Firms in Common
A, 2, 1
```

This means that 1 firm is used by client 2 AND used by a client of firm A (client 1).

This is my query so far:

```
select r1.firm, r1.client, count(distinct(r2.firm)) from relationships r1
join relationships as r2 ON r1.client = r2.client
where r1.firm = 'FIRM NAME HERE'
group by r1.firm, r1.client
```

This is returning correct results (in line with the result above with # of firms in common), but is only listing the clients that the firm already has relationships with. I'd like to also include clients that the firm does not have a relationship with.

I believe this means I need to bring in all of the clients from the Clients table for this query, but am unsure how to do so and still get the # of firms in common for each possible firm-client combination.

Would greatly appreciate any tips!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,
(
  select count(distinct firm)
  from relationships 
  where firm in (select firm from relationships where client = r.client) 
  and client <> r.client
) c
from relationships r
where firm = 'FIRM NAME HERE'
```